# Is it a war crime or act of war for a noncombatant "neutral" third party in a war to share information with either of the warring factions?

Tags: laws-of-war

There is [some discussion](https://twitter.com/rustycohl/status/1522339781665083392) from fringe Twitter users that Ukraine's artillery strike on a Russian forward command post that killed Russian senior leadership was a war crime, based on an entirely incorrect reading of international warfare laws concerning "treacherous killing", a situation which covers assassination through deception or ruse and doesn't apply here. After that was pointed out, [the user](https://twitter.com/rustycohl/status/1522403748424962049) in question [pivoted to](https://twitter.com/rustycohl/status/1522428031972913153) "The location of this forward command post was shared with Ukraine by the USA, which is an act of war or a war crime in certain circumstances", circumstances which were not expanded upon. However, I'm skeptical of this claim as well.

Is it an act of war or a war crime if, during a war between country A and country B, country C with friendly relations with country A but not officially involved in the war shares intelligence about country B with country A?

Comment: The fact that such user does not even know if it is an act of war or a war crime (which are different things) and how unspecific the "circumstances" are should tell you that it is better to stop wasting your time with that user.

Answer (score 5):

### Sharing intelligence is an act of war inconsistent with [neutrality](https://www.icrc.org/en/doc/assets/files/other/law8_final.pdf)

However, so is supplying arms to a belligerent.

> A neutral State must never assist a party to the armed conflict, in particular it must not supply warships, ammunition or other war materials directly or indirectly to a belligerent power, but otherwise its trade with the belligerent States remains unaffected.

However, it’s not a war crime.